# How Does Facebook SDK Login Work?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

If there is a github repo with the unminified source that would also work as an answer.

https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js

I'm new to oAuth in general but my assumption was that there was no way to get the auth token from an opened window. But in there example they show something like this-

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
     console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
     });
    } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
    }
});
```

When testing in Plunkr, this opened a new window, I logged in, no redirect occurred, but I was able to use the auth token. I wanted to investigate how they did this but wasn't able to find the source.

Does anyone know how they passed the token from the opened window back to the original window?

Comment: I'm interested in the same thing. Have you got any answer?

Comment: Do you know if twitter has something similar for their oAuth solution? So I can avoid the redirection